# Make Paypal accept variable as price

Tags: variables, paypal

I have recently started building a custom PC website with Serif Web X8.
I was trying to make a form that outputted its value to another page where it could be payed , after a while I managed to get some code (via hours of copy paste and edit) that was a form that sent its value to another page , however I do not know how to then get the variable that is the price and set it as the price for a paypal button.
I tried this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$finalpriceexcvat;?>">
<input type="image"           
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0"   
name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif"     
width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

But when it redirects to paypal its says "Some required information is missing or incomplete. Please correct your entries and try again."
I have gone through the code and checked it against some other html code that does the same thing, but to no avail.

Am I missing any code?
[Here is the link to a sample form.](http://www.make-my-pc.co.uk/formtest)

Comment: PayPal has its own [development knowledge](https://developer.paypal.com/) base. maybe its worth a try to visit that. You can find more about options and APIs there, pick one that fits your needs.

Comment: some basic code on this question might help.  see [ask]

Comment: Martin Serrano I have looked through the paypal developers website before and not found what I wanted

Comment: You would need to implement one of their APIs, for example the [PHP](http://www.php.net/) link. Then send them an array of values, your developers ID, account to send the money to and some other stuff. Then you make PayPal pop up and it handles the rest of the payment, giving you a reply which you know whether the payment was succesfull.  With this basic knowledge I'd start your search again. There is loads to find ;) Good luck, and if you have a concrete question head back here and [formulate well](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thankyou , sorry if my question was stupid , I'm a bit of a NOOB